# Can data from a desktop application be copied as an array to clipboard?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, desktop-application, copy-paste

I wish to copy data from my desktop application to another web solution I'm using.
At the moment, I need to take each field and copy-paste it. Is there a way to map the desktop software and clipboard the data to an array/string that I can later use?

There aren't any API's around of course.

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you could do is create a "hybrid" Desktop/Web automation script (say [TestStack.White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) / [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/)) to get data from the Desktop Application and then copy it to the Web application; but as it may be a very complex development task (depending on the structure and functionality of both applications), it may not be cost effective.